# Android C2DM ( push notification ) after first run

Tags: android, notifications, message, android-c2dm, notificationmanager

I tried to send push notifications; everything seemed fine, but 
I have a problem to pass the payload to the notification **after the first run**.

This is my code.

```
public void createNotification(Context context, String payload) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
                "Received message", System.currentTimeMillis());
        // Hide the notification after its selected
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MessageReceivedActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("payload", payload);

        Log.d("C2DM", "OK.. TRUE MESSAGE --->: payload = " + payload);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "news",
                "news...", pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    }
```

..and after, when i read the notification:

```
public class MessageReceivedActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {

            String message = extras.getString("payload");
            Log.d("C2DM", "ERROR: ALWAYS FIRST MESSAGE!! --> " + message);
            if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
                TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
                view.setText(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

The message that I sent to the second activity does not update ever!!

Comment: ---> S O L V E D <--  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);